# Problems with child theme

Tags: child-theme

I am using the "Online Shop" theme with Hebrew installation of wordpress (RTL).
I created a child theme, however the styling in messed up and RTL stopped working.
since its a free version of the theme, i managed to get minimal support. 
the support did say something like this

We have just one suggestion wp_enqueue_scripts priority make higher( in number like 9999 ), one child theme.

**what does that mean???**

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: online-shop Child
Template: online-shop
*/
```

can someone help with this please??

Comment: if you don't load `style.css` of the child theme, is everything well displayed ?

Comment: You're replacing `$parent_style` with the actual parent slug, be it `twentyfifteen-style` right?

Comment: I didnt really catch that part about the child theme. how can I know what is the actual parent slug? I guess I need to replace this `$parent_style = 'parent-style'` with something else right?

Comment: @mmm , how do I don't load style.css ?